# detect Windows Explorer copy operation

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, winapi

Is there any way to detect whenever a copy operation starts in Windows Explorer.

kind of like in SuperCopier : [SuperCopier Website](https://sourceforge.net/projects/supercopier/) ?

and log files involved in the operation ? and such ?

I've browsed through Supercopier code and I can't find the part which deals with detecting the copy operation, as I'm not fluid in Delphi.

P.S : it seems they are using a Shell Extension ...not sure though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You have to implement a [shell extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776797%28VS.85%29.aspx) which has to [hook the file copy operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144063%28VS.85%29.aspx). There are plenty of examples of how to do these things in C++ (using the native Win32 API) and also using C# or other .NET framework languages. I'm sure you can use Delphi too but I don't know the details involved in making the Win32 API calls..

Here's an article which details the [implementation of a simple shell extension in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dateparser.aspx).

Of course, you may also want to take a look at windows file I/O filters, although they only allow you to *observe* file operations such as creating, copying, changing or deleting. In .NET creating a file I/O filter is trivial using the [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) and if all you want is to *detect* and *log* such file copy operations it may be all you need to do.

**NOTE** If you decide to implement a shell extension in C#, you should know that it will only work on operating systems where the .NET framework has been installed (the version that you used to create the extension) - although most people now have at least .NET 1.1, and 2.0..

Comment: i'm interested in using C# .NET to do it.

Comment: then take a look at those links. there's a little bit of reading to do but implementing shell extensions in C# is not too hard.

Comment: Implementing Shell Ext in .NET is a no-no
http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/archive/2005/11/18/494572.aspx.

You will need to use a thin C++ wrapper + IPC into a .NET process.

Comment: well, I wouldn't say it's a no-no. Certainly it will be less-and-less of a no-no as Microsoft migrates more-and-more of the windows core towards .net. At any rate, it depends heavily on what the purpose of the extension is - i.e. public or private for your own amusement, in your own controlled environment

Comment: It ++is++ a no-no, because only one version of the .NET framework can be loaded into a process at a time. Choosing .NET 2.x for your shell extension would prohibit any others using .NET 1.x or 3.x from being loaded. And MS isn't migrating *any* of the Windows core toward .NET - .NET is an add-on on ++top++ of the Windows core (IOW, you have your dependencies reversed - .NET relies on the core and not the other way around).

Comment: With .net 4 this issue has gone and .net shell extensions are supported

Answer (score 6):

Examples of creating a copy hook shell extension can be found in the installation delphi folder \Demos\ActiveX\ShellExt\copyhook.dpr

Here you have another additional example

- [A Copy Hook for Pascal Files](http://www.marcocantu.com/md3/md3c21.htm)

Bye.

Comment: yeah, this is surely the way to go as it seems easier and less painful to write such tools with Delphi.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any Shell extension.
You just have to hook Shell apis.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to detect Windows Explorer is checking the [Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx). Of course it doesn't work in drag'n drop case, mcd command or TotalCommander.