# Bypassing Windows Copy design

Tags: c#, copy, system

I have been trying to figure out a way to streamline copying files from one drive (network or external in my case) to my main system drives. Short of creating a program that I will have to activate each time then choosing all the info in it, I have no really good design to bypass it.

I have been wondering if there was a way to intercept a straight-forward windows copy with a program to do it my way. The basic design would be that upon grabbing the copy (actually for this to be efficient, a group of different copies), the program would organize all the separate copies into a single stream of copies.

I've been wanting to do this as recently I have been needing to make backups of a lot of data and move it a lot as all my drives seem to be failing the past few months.

**EDIT**

For the moment, let's assume I am copying from a fully defragmented external drive (because I was). Let's also assume I am copying to a 99% defragmented drive (because I was). If I attempt to move every file at once, then the Windows copy method works great as it only needs to stream a contiguous file from one drive to the other (likely keeping the copy contiguous). This is basically best case, I need everything from there to move to here. So the copy method gets to grab the files in some algorithmicly logical order (typically by filename) and read then write the data to the new location.

Now for the reality of the situation, I instead copy a bunch of files from different locations (let's still assume fully defragmented as this is the case of my external), to different file locations on the second drive. I don't wish to wait for each one to finish before starting the next one, so I go through the folders picking and choosing what goes where and soon my screen is covered in COPY windows displaying the status of all the copies attempting to run at the same time. This presents a slight slowing down of the copy as a whole as each copy progresses independently of the others. That means that instead of a single contiguous file taking the total bandwidth available, all these files share the bandwidth approximately equally (this also adds in read and write delays to the disks as now the system has to grab a little from each file before circling back to the first). Still assuming best case scenario, this slower than if all the files were in one location and moved to one location.

What I want to do is intercept all the separate downloads and organize them into a list of single downloads that would happen one after another.

Comment: What does "grabbing the copy" mean?

Comment: You want to implement your own file copy function, then hook the standard Windows copy process and use your own code instead? *Why?* Chances are very low that you can write a better file copy algorithm than the Windows Shell team did. They've been at it for a while...

Comment: it does seem unlikely that somebody who is asking for help on SO is going to do better than the Windows Shell team!

Comment: There are many different copy scenarios, and the ones that the Windows shell is optimized for may be particularly bad for the OP's situation. For example, he may be copying a single source to multiple destinations, which is hard to do optimally in Explorer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect Windows Explorer copy operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585453/detect-windows-explorer-copy-operation)

Comment: Just because the Windows development team has been working on something for a long time does not mean it is the best. If that were the case there would only be one operating system in existance and one of each and every program type available, no OpenOffice, no third party IDEs, no Nvidia vs ATI. I am asking for help on StackOverflow because I am uncertain of how to do something. Nothing is the best, things are only better depending on the environment in which they are used and needed. This is why people learn, so that they can make their own environment better.

Comment: It sounds like Scott wants to have a "copy queue" where all copy-operations are appended, and a worker which does the actual copying, like a common ftp-client-implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can intercept nicely is the FileSystemWatcher.

Comment: I am unsure of how this would help me. I have used it before but only a little bit. If I attach to a file created event, would that let me know where the file came from, as that would be the only way I could then attempt to bypass the Windows copy and then attempt to copy it myself. This could also present the issue that if I do make copy a few files from one location to the same new location, the program would be unaware of this as each file is not created right away, but only when its read starts.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for

[detect Windows Explorer copy operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585453/detect-windows-explorer-copy-operation)

You need to create a Shell Extension according to this post.